# Debugger doesn't hit Module at all if I insert a breakpoint nothing is hit and giving me an error

Tags: silverlight, mef, prism-4

**I am facing problem ( Important to notice that the debugger doesn't hit 
CivicaHousingRepairsModule at all .... If I insert a breakpoint in the first line ... nothing is hit.) since last 2 days without any clue.** 
I have created sample application using Silverlight 4,PRISM 4.0 and MEF. Which contian two modules as per following.

```
//Module 1
namespace Civica.Housing.Security
{
    [ModuleExport(typeof(CivicaHousingSecurityModule),InitializationMode = InitializationMode.OnDemand)]
    public class CivicaHousingSecurityModule:IModule
    {
         private readonly IRegionManager _regionManager;
         [ImportingConstructor] //MEF magic to for resolving all the DI
         public CivicaHousingSecurityModule(IRegionManager regionManager, IAuthenticationService authenticationService)
         {
             regionManager.CheckForNull("regionManager");
             _regionManager = regionManager;
         }
         #region IModule Implementation
         public void Initialize()
         {
         } 
         #endregion
    }
}

//Module 2
namespace Civica.Housing.Repairs
{
    [ModuleExport(typeof(CivicaHousingRepairsModule), InitializationMode = InitializationMode.OnDemand)]
    public class CivicaHousingRepairsModule : IModule
    {
        private readonly IRegionManager _regionManager;
        #region Constructor
        [ImportingConstructor] 
        public CivicaHousingRepairsModule(IRegionManager regionManager, IAuthenticationService authenticationService)
        {
            regionManager.CheckForNull("regionManager");
            _regionManager = regionManager;
        }
        #endregion
        #region IModule Implementation
        public void Initialize()
        {
            _regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.ContentRegion, typeof(TestView));
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Now following is the code for regestring Module (**ModuleCatalog.xaml**).

```
<Modularity:ModuleCatalog xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
                          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
                          xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" 
                          xmlns:Modularity="clr-
namespace:Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity;assembly=Microsoft.Practices.Prism">
    <Modularity:ModuleInfo Ref="Civica.Housing.Security.xap" InitializationMode="OnDemand" 
ModuleName="CivicaHousingSecurityModule" />
    <Modularity:ModuleInfo Ref="Civica.Housing.Repairs.xap" InitializationMode="OnDemand" 
ModuleName="CivicaHousingRepairsModule" />
</Modularity:ModuleCatalog>
```

Now following is the code for **Bootstrapper**

```
 public class CivicaHousingBootstrapper : MefBootstrapper
    {
        private const string ModuleCatalogUri = 

"/Civica.Housing.App;component/ModulesCatalog.xaml";
.
.
.
 protected override Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog()
        {
            var moduleCatalog=Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.ModuleCatalog.CreateFromXaml

(new Uri(ModuleCatalogUri,


UriKind.Relative));
            return moduleCatalog;            
        }
.
.
.
}
```

**PROBLEM:**

When I navigate from one module (Security) to another (Repairs) then it will give me the following **Error**

```
Webpage error details
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 
2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; 
Tablet PC 2.0)
Timestamp: Wed, 22 Feb 2012 13:18:00 UTC
Message: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application 
Code: 4004    
Category: ManagedRuntimeError   
Message: Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.ModuleInitializeException: An exception 
occurred while initializing module 'CivicaHousingRepairsModule'. 
    - The exception message was: The composition remains unchanged. The changes were rejected 
because of the following error(s): The composition produced multiple composition errors, with 3 
root causes. The root causes are provided below. Review the CompositionException.Errors property 
for more detailed information.
1) More than one export was found that matches the constraint '((exportDefinition.ContractName == 
"Civica.Housing.Services.IRepairsDataService") AndAlso (exportDefinition.Metadata.ContainsKey
("ExportTypeIdentity") AndAlso "Civica.Housing.Services.IRepairsDataService".Equals

(exportDefinition.Metadata.get_Item("ExportTypeIdentity"))))'.

Resulting in: Cannot set import 'Civica.Housing.Security.ViewModels.DashboardViewModel..ctor 

(Parameter="_iRepairsDataService", ContractName="Civica.Housing.Services.IRepairsDataService")' 

on part 'Civica.Housing.Security.ViewModels.DashboardViewModel'.
Element: Civica.Housing.Security.ViewModels.DashboardViewModel..ctor 

(Parameter="_iRepairsDataService", ContractName="Civica.Housing.Services.IRepairsDataService") 

-->  Civica.Housing.Security.ViewModels.DashboardViewModel -->  AssemblyCatalog 

(Assembly="Civica.Housing.Security, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null")

2) More than one export was found that matches the constraint '((exportDefinition.ContractName == 

"Civica.Housing.Services.IRepairsDataService") AndAlso (exportDefinition.Metadata.ContainsKey

("ExportTypeIdentity") AndAlso "Civica.Housing.Services.IRepairsDataService".Equals

(exportDefinition.Metadata.get_Item("ExportTypeIdentity"))))'.

Resulting in: Cannot set import 'Civica.Housing.Security.ViewModels.ShortcutViewModel..ctor 

(Parameter="_iRepairsDataService", ContractName="Civica.Housing.Services.IRepairsDataService")' 

on part 'Civica.Housing.Security.ViewModels.ShortcutViewModel'.
Element: Civica.Housing.Security.ViewModels.ShortcutViewModel..ctor 

(Parameter="_iRepairsDataService", ContractName="Civica.Housing.Services.IRepairsDataService") 

-->  Civica.Housing.Security.ViewModels.ShortcutViewModel -->  AssemblyCatalog 

(Assembly="Civica.Housing.Security, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null")

3) More than one export was found that matches the constraint '((exportDefinition.ContractName == 

"Civica.Housing.Services.IRepairsDataService") AndAlso (exportDefinition.Metadata.ContainsKey

("ExportTypeIdentity") AndAlso "Civica.Housing.Services.IRepairsDataService".Equals

(exportDefinition.Metadata.get_Item("ExportTypeIdentity"))))'.

Resulting in: Cannot set import 'Civica.Housing.Security.ViewModels.HeaderViewModel..ctor 

(Parameter="_iRepairsDataService", ContractName="Civica.Housing.Services.IRepairsDataService")' 

on part 'Civica.Housing.Security.ViewModels.HeaderViewModel'.
Element: Civica.Housing.Security.ViewModels.HeaderViewModel..ctor 

(Parameter="_iRepairsDataService", ContractName="Civica.Housing.Services.IRepairsDataService") 

-->  Civica.Housing.Security.ViewModels.HeaderViewModel -->  AssemblyCatalog 

(Assembly="Civica.Housing.Security, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null")

    Check the InnerException property of the exception for more information. If the exception 

occurred 
    while creating an object in a DI container, you can exception.GetRootException() to help 

locate the 
    root cause of the problem.  ---> System.ComponentModel.Composition.ChangeRejectedException: 

The composition remains unchanged. The changes were rejected because of the following error(s): 

The composition produced multiple composition errors, with 3 root causes. The root causes are 

provided below. Review the CompositionException.Errors property for more detailed information.

1) More than one export was found that matches the constraint '((exportDefinition.ContractName == 

"Civica.Housing.Services.IRepairsDataService") AndAlso (exportDefinition.Metadata.ContainsKey

("ExportTypeIdentity") AndAlso "Civica.Housing.Services.IRepairsDataService".Equals

(exportDefinition.Metadata.get_Item("ExportTypeIdentity"))))'.

Resulting in: Cannot set import 'Civica.Housing.Security.ViewModels.DashboardViewModel..ctor 

(Parameter="_iRepairsDataService", ContractName="Civica.Housing.Services.IRepairsDataService")' 

on part 'Civica.Housing.Security.ViewModels.DashboardViewModel'.
Element: Civica.Housing.Security.ViewModels.DashboardViewModel..ctor 

(Parameter="_iRepairsDataService", ContractName="Civica.Housing.Services.IRepairsDataService") 

-->  Civica.Housing.Security.ViewModels.DashboardViewModel -->  AssemblyCatalog 

(Assembly="Civica.Housing.Security, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null")

2) More than one export was found that matches the constraint '((exportDefinition.ContractName == 

"Civica.Housing.Services.IRepairsDataService") AndAlso (exportDefinition.Metadata.ContainsKey

("ExportTypeIdentity") AndAlso "Civica.Housing.Services.IRepairsDataService".Equals

(exportDefinition.Metadata.get_Item("ExportTypeIdentity"))))'.

Resulting in: Cannot set import 'Civica.Housing.Security.ViewModels.ShortcutViewModel..ctor 

(Parameter="_iRepairsDataService", ContractName="Civica.Housing.Services.IRepairsDataService")' 

on part 'Civica.Housing.Security.ViewModels.ShortcutViewModel'.
Element: Civica.Housing.Security.ViewModels.ShortcutViewModel..ctor 

(Parameter="_iRepairsDataService", ContractName="Civica.Housing.Services.IRepairsDataService") 

-->  Civica.Housing.Security.ViewModels.ShortcutViewModel -->  AssemblyCatalog 

(Assembly="Civica.Housing.Security, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null")

3) More than one export was found that matches the constraint '((exportDefinition.ContractName == 

"Civica.Housing.Services.IRepairsDataService") AndAlso (exportDefinition.Metadata.ContainsKey

("ExportTypeIdentity") AndAlso "Civica.Housing.Services.IRepairsDataService".Equals

(exportDefinition.Metadata.get_Item("ExportTypeIdentity"))))'.

Resulting in: Cannot set import 'Civica.Housing.Security.ViewModels.HeaderViewModel..ctor 

(Parameter="_iRepairsDataService", ContractName="Civica.Housing.Services.IRepairsDataService")' 

on part 'Civica.Housing.Security.ViewModels.HeaderViewModel'.
Element: Civica.Housing.Security.ViewModels.HeaderViewModel..ctor 

(Parameter="_iRepairsDataService", ContractName="Civica.Housing.Services.IRepairsDataService") 

-->  Civica.Housing.Security.ViewModels.HeaderViewModel -->  AssemblyCatalog 

(Assembly="Civica.Housing.Security, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null")

   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.CompositionResult.ThrowOnErrors(AtomicComposition 

atomicComposition)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.OnExportsChanging

(ExportsChangeEventArgs e)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CatalogExportProvider.OnCatalogChanging(Object 

sender, ComposablePartCatalogChangeEventArgs e)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ComposablePartCatalogCollection.OnChanging(Object 

sender, ComposablePartCatalogChangeEventArgs e)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.AggregateCatalog.OnChanging

(ComposablePartCatalogChangeEventArgs e)
   at 

System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ComposablePartCatalogCollection.RaiseChangingEvent

(Lazy`1 addedDefinitions, Lazy`1 removedDefinitions, AtomicComposition atomicComposition)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ComposablePartCatalogCollection.Add

(ComposablePartCatalog item)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.Modularity.MefModuleInitializer.CreateModule

(ModuleInfo moduleInfo)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.ModuleInitializer.Initialize(ModuleInfo moduleInfo)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.ModuleInitializer.HandleModuleInitializationError

(ModuleInfo moduleInfo, String assemblyName, Exception exception)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.ModuleInitializer.Initialize(ModuleInfo moduleInfo)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.ModuleManager.InitializeModule(ModuleInfo moduleInfo)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.ModuleManager.LoadModulesThatAreReadyForLoad()
   at Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.ModuleManager.IModuleTypeLoader_LoadModuleCompleted

(Object sender, LoadModuleCompletedEventArgs e)
   at 

Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.Modularity.MefXapModuleTypeLoader.RaiseLoadModuleComplete

d(LoadModuleCompletedEventArgs e)
   at 

Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.Modularity.MefXapModuleTypeLoader.RaiseLoadModuleComplete

d(ModuleInfo moduleInfo, Exception error)
   at 

Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.Modularity.MefXapModuleTypeLoader.HandleDownloadCompleted

(DeploymentCatalog deploymentCatalog, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
   at 

Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.Modularity.MefXapModuleTypeLoader.DeploymentCatalog_Downl

oadCompleted(Object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.DeploymentCatalog.OnDownloadCompleted

(AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.DeploymentCatalog.HandleOpenReadCompleted(Object 

sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
   at System.Net.WebClient.OnOpenReadCompleted(OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
   at System.Net.WebClient.OpenReadOperationCompleted(Object arg)     

Line: 56
Char: 13
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost:61228/Civica.Housing.aspx
```

**Important Note:** The debugger doesn't hit CivicaHousingRepairsModule at all If I insert a

breakpoint in the first line nothing is hit.

**I tried following**:
1. I have set all the PRISM dll's to localcopy to false.

Please do let me know if you have faced the same problem and you have a good solution for it. Your answers or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: is there any one who has passion to read above questions ;) uhhhhhhhh thanks for reading.

Comment: Have you tried turning off the `Debug | Options and Settings | General | Enable Just My Code (Managed Only)` option. Sometimes the debugger can get a bit confused as to where the files are coming from. Turning off that option usually allows breakpoint to be set anywhere.

Comment: This happens to me often in Silverlight 4 (not specific to MEF or Prism)...  ALL SL debugging becomes inactive.  I go into the properties of the web project, remove the xap, save, and re-add it.

Comment: The error states a problem with registration of `IRepairsDataService` so probably the module will not be created at all (and you won't hit a breakpoint). Are you sure the `IRepairsDataService` is properly registered? Are able to debug the app at all (any place before creation of the modules ie. can you put a breakpoint in the bootstrapper)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its becoz ur xap file doesnot exist or is in corrupt format. please delete all ur xap files from web project and then rebuild ur application module by module and then try to run your application

Comment: Thanks yrahman. I will try it. still it gives error.Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

In your modules project, you must config CopyLocal = 'false' for all Prism references, otherwise, in MainProject, it should be CopyLocal= 'true'.
It worked for me.